# How to avoid that an insertion pattern using sed is applied to the middle of a string?

Tags: sed

**Aim**

The aim is to convert the following string:

```
hello_hello,123-world567-helloworld123456,world1234-hello09876
```

using sed into a specific format.

**Attempts**

```
sed -e 's|^\(hello_[a-z0-9]\{3\}\)\(.*\)|\1,\1\2|g;s|..|&/|g' /tmp/file
```

**Expected outcome**

```
he/ll/o_/he/ll/o,123-world567-helloworld123456,/wo/rl/d1/23/4-/he/ll/o0/98/76/
```

**Current outcome**

The problem is that every 2 characters a `/` is inserted. The insertion of `/` should be avoided in the part that resides between the two commas.

```
he/ll/o_/he/ll/o,/12/3-/wo/rl/d5/67/-h/el/lo/wo/rl/d1/23/45/6,/wo/rl/d1/23/4-/he/ll/o0/98/76/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can do it like:

```
sed 's|\(,[^,]*,\)\{0,1\}\([^,]\{1,2\}\)|\1/\2|g
' <<\IN                                     
hello_hello,123-world567-helloworld123456,world1234-hello09876
IN
```

...which prints...

```
/he/ll/o_/he/ll/o,123-world567-helloworld123456,/wo/rl/d1/23/4-/he/ll/o0/98/76
```

So *most* of the changes made are done to the second `s///`ubstitution - but that's because I removed all of the first.

So the biggest part of your problem was that you were simply telling `sed` to substitute in a `/` after every two characters - the `.` dots mean *any char* and the `g` means global - or *all*.

The second biggest part was that the first substitution was not helping you - and was completely unnecessary.

More than that though, you were also inserting an extra comma in the first substitution - so after I'd get the first bit straightened out, I was still running into extra fields. Look:

```
\(,[^,]*,\)\{0,1\}\([^,]\{1,2\}\)|\1/\2
```

That's the substitution statement that worked for me, and heres why:

- `\(,[^,]*,\)\{0,1\}` - in a global context you have to be careful to get only as much as you need. You were substituting for every two chars and so that's what you got - `sed` is *greedy*. This is referenced first - which is important - because as `sed` reads left to right it will usually just insert a slash between every two sequential not comma chars, but it if it encounters a comma it will read in up to the next it finds and save the whole block to `\1` without inserting any slashes at all.
- `\([^,]\{1,2\}\)` - You can't use the `.` dots here - they will match a comma and so you'll just wind up writing in the slashes after you skip a delimiter. You need to explicitly exclude commas. And so that is what this does - every sequence of 1 or 2 of them - though `sed` will always pull the largest one of those numbers that it might.

One difference I can see between this and that in your example is the first slash here is at the head of the string and there is no trailing slash, whereas yours does the opposite. To remedy that, as needed:

```
...;s|^/\(.*/.\)/*$|\1/|...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will come up with a pure `sed` approach but I find using a program that understands input fields, and not just lines, much easier for this sort of thing:

1. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -F, -lane 'for($F[0],$F[2]){s|(..)|\1/|g;} print join ",",@F' /tmp/file 
   he/ll/o_/he/ll/o,123-world567-helloworld123456,wo/rl/d1/23/4-/he/ll/o0/98/76/
   ```

   #### Explanation

   - `-a` : split each input lines into fields and save them in the `@F` array. The 1dt field will be `$F[0]`, the 2nd `$F[1]` and so on.
   - `-F` : set the field delimiter to `,`.
   - `-n` and `-e` : Read each input line (`-n`) and apply the script given by `-e`.
   - `-l` : remove trailing newlines and add a `\n` to each `print` call.
   - `for($F[0],$F[2]){}` : apply this to the first and third fields.
   - `s|(..)|\1/|g;` : simple substitution, it will add a `/` after every second character.
   - `print join ",",@F'` : join the list of fields with commas and print. Since the fields were already altered in the previous step, this will print the changed ones.
2. GNU awk

   ```
   $ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$1=gensub(/(..)/,"\\1/","g",$1); $3=gensub(/(..)/,"\\1/","g",$3);}1;' /tmp/file 
   he/ll/o_/he/ll/o,123-world567-helloworld123456,wo/rl/d1/23/4-/he/ll/o0/98/76/
   ```

   #### Explanation

   As above, the `-F` sets the field delimiter. `-v OFS=","` sets the output delimiter to `,`. Then, the `gensub()` function (GNU awk only, I believe) runs the substitution. Here, it is run on the 1st and third fields.

Comment: `sed` does understand fields - BREs implement all kinds of numeric references for pattern occurrence - the fields are defined as patterns. And beyond BRE there is the `s///[num]` syntax as well. There is no assumption made about a default field delimiter - that is at the `sed`er's discretion - of course, but field handling is a pretty basic `sed` function. Oh - and a `/g`lobal `s///`ubstitution works out exactly in the way another application might do a field delimited context - it splits the *line* into delimited fields and operates on each by pattern.